# css 2 columns, dynamic content. Scroll on right column only without going over window width

Tags: css

I am well versed in CSS and yet, have not found a solution all day.

I am targeting IE9+ and am not interested in a JavaScript/jQuery solution. (At least not until I've exhausted any viable CSS option)

I have a complex 2 column layout for a web app.  Both columns have dynamic content.  The left column needs to expand to fit it's content without scroll bars.  The right column could potentially have very large content that needs to be accessible, so the right column needs to be able to scroll independently.
The problem is I can't set a width of 100% on the right column since that goes over the window width.  Ordinarily I would set a negative left margin to counter that, but since I don't know how wide the left column would be I can't do that here.
I thought maybe some type of hacky `display: table-cell;` would work, (or gasp, using actual tables) but alas, haven't been successful that way either.
JSFiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/nARqR/
Seems like a common use-case.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: does it need to scroll horizontally?

Comment: yes, the right column content needs to scroll horizontally, as well as vertically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way i can think of is by doing this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nARqR/1/)):

```
.left {
    background-color: #ccc;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.right {
    background-color: #666;   
    color: #ccc;
}
```

But you'll have issues with padding on the right div since part of it is hidden behind the left div (since it is floated)

Comment: Color me humbled, I do believe that's all I needed. In reality it's a lot more complex, but other things aside this seems to be all I need. Thank you very much!